# TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined in nodejs mongoose

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

Here is the code

```
const {validationResult} = require('express-validator');
const bcrypt = require('bcryptjs');
const jwt = require('jsonwebtoken');
const User = require('../models/user');


exports.login = (req, res, next) => {
const email = req.body.email;
const password = req.body.password;
let loadedUser;
User.findOne({email:email})
.then(user => {
    if(user){
        loadedUser = user;
        return bcrypt.compare(password, user.password);
    } else{
        const error = new Error('EMAILID_NOT_FOUND');
        error.statusCode = 401;
        throw error;
    }

})
.then(
    isEqual => {
        console.log(isEqual);
        if(!isEqual){
            const error = new Error('WRONG_PASSWORD');
            console.log(error)
            error.statusCode = 401;
            throw error;
        }
        const token = jwt.sign({
            email: loadedUser.email,
            userId: loadedUser._id.toString()
        },'somesecrekey',{expiresIn:'7d'}
        );
        res.status(200).json({
            token: token,
            userId: loadedUser._id.toString()
        });
        })
        .catch(err => {
            if(!err.statusCode){
                err.statusCode =500;
            }
            next(err);
        });
};

app.js

const express = require('express');
const bodyparser = require('body-parser');
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const path = require('path');

const eventRoutes = require('./routes/eventRouter');
const companyRoutes = require('./routes/companyRouter');
const authrouter = require('./routes/authrouter');

const app = express();

// app.use(bodyparser.urlencoded());

app.use(bodyparser.json()); //application/json
app.use('/images',express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'images'))); 

app.use((req, res, next)=>{
res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, POST, PUT, PATCH, 
DELETE');
res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Content-Type, Authorization');
next();
})

app.use('/auth', authrouter);
app.use('/event', eventRoutes);
app.use('/company',companyRoutes);

app.use((error, req, res, next)=>{
const status = error.statusCode || 500;
const message = error.message;
const data = error.data;
const errmsg = data[0].msg;
res.status(status).json({ error: message, errmsg: errmsg, data: data });
});

mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/scope').then(result=>{
app.listen(8080)   
}).catch(err => console.log(err));
```

I'm trying to do authentication in nodejs and mongoose

when the user presses log in the api will get called with the body of email and password when the control comes to the login function it will check for email exists or not in the database and checks for password is correct or not

Here I'm getting the error as **TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined**

with the error message

```
Error: WRONG_PASSWORD
at User.findOne.then.then.isEqual (F:\Codebase\Ack 
Codebase\SCOPE\scope_server\controllers\authcontroller.js:63:31)
App Error: WRONG_PASSWORD
TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined
at app.use (F:\Codebase\Ack Codebase\SCOPE\scope_server\app.js:34:24)
at Layer.handle_error (F:\Codebase\Ack 
Codebase\SCOPE\scope_server\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:71:5)
at trim_prefix (F:\Codebase\Ack 
Codebase\SCOPE\scope_server\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:315:13)
at F:\Codebase\Ack 
Codebase\SCOPE\scope_server\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:284:7
at Function.process_params (F:\Codebase\Ack 
Codebase\SCOPE\scope_server\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:335:12)
at Immediate.next (F:\Codebase\Ack 
Codebase\SCOPE\scope_server\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:275:10)
at Immediate.<anonymous> (F:\Codebase\Ack 
Codebase\SCOPE\scope_server\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:635:15)
at runCallback (timers.js:706:11)
at tryOnImmediate (timers.js:676:5)
at processImmediate (timers.js:658:5)
```

Please help
thanks

Comment: What is the output of `console.log(isEqual)`?

Comment: This kind of error generally happen when you try to access something that is `null`

Comment: The error says `at app.use (F:\Codebase\Ack Codebase\SCOPE\scope_server\app.js:34:24)`. What is at line `34` of  `app.js`?

Comment: @JorgePires the output of console.log(isEqual) is false

Comment: @JorgePires i have added the app.js code

Comment: @JorgePires the line 34 has following code    const errmsg = data[0].msg;

Comment: `errmsg = data[0].msg` <- it means you are not giving data to `data` before accessing. Make sure you feed the `data` arrays before it is access. The error says that you are trying to access something that does not exist.

Comment: Print out `data`, something like `console.log( data )` after `const data = error.data;`, this will give a clear idea of the `data` format.

Comment: @JorgePires you are right i was not providing to the array to send back the response thanks

Comment: Glad things turned out just fine! Keep it up!